# Converting WGS 84 Coordinates to Arc 1950 coordinates using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, convert, wgs84

I am using ArcMap.

How can I convert [WGS 84](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?gml=urn:ogc:def:datum:EPSG::6326) coordinates to [Arc 1950][35s] coordinates?

e.g

```
S12.14127 E25.96643
S12.23535 E25.90588
S12.23535 E25.90588
S12.23859 E25.79461
S12.27073 E25.66638
```

Comment: Data is in Zambia. Arc 1950 to WGS 84 (8) AKA EPSG:1120. The accuracy of the transformation is not very good; but it's all that's available.

Answer (score 0):

You just subtract 300metres for every coordinate on the northings value. Wgs 84 uses the wgs ellipsoid whilst arc 1950 uses Clarke 1880 so the difference is 300m on the northings value. The Eastings value remain the same in UTM